# How to get the end position of a regex (PCRE) in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I using the matches optionnal parameter with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag.
I get the start offset and the matching expression.... 
I don't find the options to get the end of the matching expression like in Java Regexes.
Is there a solution or my last resort is : offset + strlen(matching_string) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `\G` - that's the position of the regex engine after the previous match.

However, I don't find this any better than your "last resort" method. What's so bad about that?

Comment: Never used \G before. Do u mean (\G) would return the position or do u mean  reg1\Greg2 will make reg2 to be matched after reg1. Need to look at the documentation. Well its just that in Java you get both end & start so I was looking for the same fonctionnality.

Comment: Found some info there http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html... does it work with PHP preg_match ??? neet to try that.

Answer (score 3):

Just put a `(.)` at the end of your regex and take the captured offset of that ;)

Comment: Clever but what if there is no data behind ?. Seems it won't work.

Comment: @millebii Use lookbehind: `(?<=.)`

Comment: @millebi: If it may be the end, you could use `(.|$)`. Just like you always do ;)

Comment: @millebii: The empty match `()` would be the most universal option.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is like Perl, there should be a couple of arrays of offsets for all the matches.

In Perl its @- and @+ .. Index 1 .. is capture group offsets. Index 0 is the total match offsets.

```
if ('012345678' =~ /4/ ) {
    print "Match start = $-[0], match end = $+[0]\n";
}
```

Prints `Match start = 4, match end = 5`

Comment: yes that's the point, but they are not accessible. You are not really answering the point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but i could not use

```
 strlen(matching_string)
```

Cause matching string was a regex with variable amount characters.

Instead I used **preg_replace** the matching string and worked from there.

I guess it similar to @NikiC suggestion but it took me a while to figure out.

Hope this helps.